# What ruby construct allows as to do user.articles.create (...) where "articles" returns an array and create is called on association object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm seeing the above on rails and doesn't feel natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Association proxies in Active Record are middlemen between the object that holds the association, known as the @owner, and the actual associated object, known as the @target." `user.articles` is not an Array actually, it's an instance of CollectionProxy.

See [CollectionProxy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy).

Answer (score 0):

`articles` is not an `Array`, it's an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

This explains the rest :)

Comment: You're right. But when I do User.first.articles.class I get `=> Array`.

Comment: @user25464, see the link provided in Yanhao's answer.